# How does converting the primitive str through multiple "as" casts work?

Tags: pointers, rust, type-conversion

Here is what I found in Rust's [source code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/96909179d9ec80db286605876ce67659dd16fd4b/src/libcore/str/mod.rs). I have difficulty in understanding `&mut *(self as *mut str as *mut [u8])` and `self as *const str as *const u8`.

Is it a two-step conversion? First convert to a `*mut str` or `*const str`, next as a `*mut [u8]` or `*const u8`?

```
#[stable(feature = "str_mut_extras", since = "1.20.0")]
#[inline(always)]
pub unsafe fn as_bytes_mut(&mut self) -> &mut [u8] {
    &mut *(self as *mut str as *mut [u8])
}
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
#[inline]
pub const fn as_ptr(&self) -> *const u8 {
    self as *const str as *const u8
}
```

Comment: *Is it a two-step conversion* — I'm having trouble imagining what *else* it could be... what other possibilities do you see?

Comment: Note that this is not strictly speaking a _conversion_: the data is not modified by it and the compiler doesn't emit any code for it. It's more a _reinterpretation_: it changes the way the compiler looks at the data and the set of operations that can be applied to the data without changing the data itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rust, the `as` operator allows converting by *one* step at a time.

There are a few conversions allowed, such as:

- `&T` to `*const T`,
- `&mut T` to `*mut T`,
- `*mut T` to `*mut U` (pending some conditions on T and U),
- ...

However, even though you can go `&mut T` to `*mut T` to `*mut U` using `as` twice, you cannot go directly from `&mut T` to `*mut U`; both because compiler and humans would have a hard time figuring out the intermediate steps.

---

So, what's this conversion sequence about?

- Going from reference to pointer: typical `&T` to `*const T`, or the `mut` variant.
- Going from pointer to `str` to pointer to `[u8]`: a typical `*const T` to `*const U` for adequates `T` and `U`. `str` actually has the same representation as `[u8]`, but only a subset of values are valid (proper UTF-8 ones).

It's interesting to note that one is safe and not the other:

- Since all `str` are `[u8]`, converting from `*str` to `*[u8]` is always safe.
- However, exposing `&mut [u8]` allows breaking invariants inside `str`, and therefore `as_bytes_mut` is `unsafe`.